# make a spinner selectively translate strings

Tags: java, xml, translate

I am trying to make a spinner I have selectively translate strings on a page. I have my app set up to translate the bulk of the page based on locale languages already. In the image below, The locale language will effect the top string, but I have a spinner on my home page that has all the available android languages in it, and I want users to be able to select one of the spinner items, and as a result the bottom string in the picture below will be translated to that language. I can't find a way to set it up, all the advice I've seen so far is just how to configure the application to set up locale language's. Any direction would be greatly appreciated!

[image]

Comment: Show your code for better understanding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use [Android-LocalizationActivity](https://github.com/akexorcist/Android-LocalizationActivity)

Here a portion of its readme:

> It's basic for android application to be supported multiple languages. Yeah! It's very easy because android has String Resource. Developer just had to prepare the text for different languages then android system will use itself. But frequently problem is "On-time Language Changing". Because the String Resource was designed to be depending on current device language. but if we want to change the language by click some button. It will be difficult to handle it. This problem will solved because I have created a new library to handle application language. It called "**Localization Activity**" library.

It's so simple to implement it. Just extend your `Activity` with `LocalizationActivity`. Here a sample code with Button:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

import com.akexorcist.localizationactivity.LocalizationActivity;

public class MainActivity extends LocalizationActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_simple);

    findViewById(R.id.btn_th).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.btn_en).setOnClickListener(this);
  }

  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    int id = v.getId();
    if (id == R.id.btn_en) {
      setLanguage("en");
    } else if (id == R.id.btn_th) {
      setLanguage("th");
    }
  }
}
```

When user click `btn_th` (Thailand), all language will be translated to Thai language. So you only need to adjust it with spinner.

Comment: You're welcome. Could this accepted as an answer?..:)

Comment: yeah it certainly could!